# How do I reference a file from within my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, path, classpath, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.0.1.  I have a Java class file in my project located at

```
bin/java/WordToTextConverter.class
```

How do I reference this class from within a Rails file?  For instance, in one of my service classes I have this

```
`java -classpath "#{Rails.configuration.java_class_path}" WordToTextConverter ${file_location} #{file_as_text}`
```

but this is currently failing because I haven't put in the correct path to "WordToTextConverter".  What should that path be?

Comment: Didn't even know about it.  But it words perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Rails.root` which would give you the full path of your current Rails application like:

```
/some_directory/rails_project/
```

So this way you can access the `bin/` folder or any other you need to work with, so in your case you could try with:

```
"#{Rails.root}/bin/java"
```

Comment: you can also just do `Rails.root.join('bin', 'java')` or `Rails.root.join('bin/java')`...probably just personal preference, but I like these more than interpolating the path name into a string